# Angular 4 Cambia headers

Tags: laravel, angularjs-2.0, http-post, cabeceras-http

Estoy implementando una api que realice en laravel, sin ningún problema al testear con Postman, pero al hacer la conexión con Angular 4, como tengo que enviar headers personalizados, estos modifican el method de POST a OPTIONS, por lo cual los endpoints no funcionan correctamente, hay una forma de agregar los headers que no provoque que se cambien el method en el Request??

Esta es la peticion que hago

```
login (loginObj: LoginObject): Observable<Session> {
let headers = new Headers();
headers.set('Content-type',['application/json']);
return this.http.post(this.basePath+'user/login',JSON.stringify(loginObj),{headers:headers})
.map(this.extractData);
```

}

Este es el request que se genera

`OPTIONS /user/login HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8000
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://localhost:4200
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0; SM-G900P Build/LRX21T) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Mobile Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:4200/login
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: es-419,es;q=0.8,en;q=0.6`

PD. si quito los headers si se envia correctamente, pero necesito enviar cabezeras personalizadas

Answer (score 0):

Tu aplicación envía primero petición OPTIONS conocida como `pre-flight` al servidor ya que es una petición a una URL o puerto diferente al origen de la petición, esto se conoce como [CORS (Cross Origin Resource Scripting)](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) y puedes leer mas sobre esto [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

Tu servidor debe de ser capaz de analizar y contestar esta petición con los headers necesarios (Access-Control-Allow-Credentials, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Access-Control-Allow-Methods, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, etc…)

Si crear un endpoint en tu API de laraver para el metodo OPTIONS que regrese el header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` vas a permitir que las tu aplicación en Angular pueda enviar la petición original sin ningún problema.